# VGA to HDMI conversion

Tags: hdmi, vga

I've been trying to help an ailing friend get an old T61 laptop (runs W10 on SSD good enough for web browsing) connected to a Panasonic TH-58PX68U large screen TV (c. 2008) via laptop VGA port thru an active (sort of?) Vention VGA to HDMI adapter. I tested the adapter on my Philips 325E monitor with no problems, even with no power to the adapter.

The T61 detects the Panasonic but there's still no picture. I have already tried every resolution/refresh I could find. The last time I tried with my T450 thru the VGA port on the docking station, it worked fine on a bunch of different, lower resolutions.

I'm blaming the TV, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Have you connected power to the input on the Vention adaptor?

Comment: Also, which device is the VGA connected to? The [Vention adaptor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/VENTION-Converter-Computer-Display-Projector/dp/B07D51QCFF?th=1) I can find says that it is VGA out to HDMI in on the monitor, not the other way around.

Comment: I think you'd have better luck getting a [VGA to composite/RCA (yellow/red/white) adapter](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?kw=vga to composite) which are both analog

Comment: Thx! Re "laptop VGA port thru.... VGA to HDMI adapter." Tested both with and with out power to adapter. I think I have VGA to composite converter hiding in a box in the garage somewhere along with the bulky connection cables. Was hoping to avoid that route. I initially tried miracast until I realized T61 video was at WDDM 1.1 with no path to upgrade.